# Python unicode terminal output

Tags: python, unicode, terminal

Please help me, I tried a lot of technics, but I cant make python print utf-8 symbols on the screen.

I need simply to read from a utf-8 coded standard input stream, count  characters and print their occurrences on the screen.

Here is my code:

```
import re
from collections import Counter
import sys
import codecs

sys.stdin = codecs.getreader('utf-8')(sys.stdin)
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout)
chars = re.findall(r'.', sys.stdin.read().lower())
counted_chars = Counter(chars).most_common(20)
print counted_chars
```

I tried this

```
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

But this was not working. I constantly get on the screen something like:

```
(u'\u043e', 90)
```

and these characters  (u'\u043e') for some reason are not displayed as a normal letters.

But if I in console do following:

```
>>> a = u'\u043e'
>>> print a
```

everything is fine and I get

What am I doing wrong? 
Please explain me or point me to right link. I have been searched for more then three hours and have no success in solving my problem.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: `re.findall(r'.', ..)` is useless here; a unicode string is a sequence by itself. If you want to avoid splitting characters that consist of several unicode codepoints (e.g., `ё`); you could use [`regex.findall(ur'\X', ..)`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex)

Comment: Unfortunately it matches nothing.The \X escape matches any number of Unicode characters that form an extended Unicode sequence. But how it is used?

Comment: 1. click the link: `regex` is not in stdlib ([yet](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0429/)) but it is backward compatible with `re`. 2. both pattern and the input string should be Unicode: `regex.findall(ur'\X', u'ёлка')`. Compare it with `re.findall(ur'.', u'ёлка')`. (add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of source file to allow utf-8 in string literals). To print it: `print " | ".join(result_of_findall)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Counter.most_common()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) returns a list of tuples, when printing data structures in Python like tuples and lists any inner object has its representation printed (whatever `repr(x)` would return).

To print the characters using `str()` instead of `repr()` you will need to iterate this list and print them separately, for example:

```
for char, count in counted_chars:
    print char, count
```